# EditText Drawable Tint not possible?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use tint for icons for whole my app.

Example in my `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle"
    android:tint="@color/red_color"/>
```

I also use some of the icons in `EditText` as its drawable:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/medium_margin_padding"
    android:hint="@string/password_text"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

However, I can't find any code that can be used to tint the drawable in `EditText`. Is it not possible to tint the drawable?

**Note:**

I use appcompat and design support library, but still can't find any code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `wrap, setTint, setTintMode` methods from the [DrawableCompat class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) to set tint for drawable programmatically

```
Drawable drawable = getyourdrawablehere;
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.GREEN);
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

And after set the drawable for the editText:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Change `PorterDuff.Mode` to `SRC_IN`

Answer (score 13):

Create a drawable with a bitmap tag like this

**drawable_with_tint.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/ic_lock"
android:tint="#fff">

</bitmap>
```

Then you may use the drawable in your edittext

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_drawable_with_tint"
android:drawablePadding="@dimen/medium_margin_padding"
android:hint="@string/password_text"
android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a bitmap a bit transluscent?

Comment: I don't use any tintMode. No the only change the icon color to other. Usually I achieve it by using tint in ImageView.

Comment: There is no "android:tint" in EditText

Comment: "android:tint" in the drawable

Comment: Oh, but it doesn't work. Anyway, solution in other answer works :)

Comment: Seems it's not working in Kitkat as well. But I don't see any warning in IDE.

Comment: @AliNematiHayati yub. but you wont need to do this for vectors because you can immediately change the colors on the vector xml.

Comment: Yes, but then you have to change the original graphical asset provided by the designer, which is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @AliNematiHayati why not ? you can create multiple instance of the original vector and modify it according to your needs. ex. vector_white, vector_gray, vector_black...  I don't think there's a problem with it.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately the solution posted by mbelsky needed some very small changes. In order to tint your drawable in your EditText you need to use `wrap` `setTint` and `setTintMode`. The full solution for all API's:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableID/mipmapID);
            emailDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(emailDrawable);
            DrawableCompat.setTint(emailDrawable,getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
            DrawableCompat.setTintMode(emailDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
android:drawableTint="@color/yourcolor"
```

Note that it only works on Api 23 or higher

Comment: Hoping that the Google Android team add compatibility for API 23- to it to get us rid of writing a lot of code as shown above!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the accepted answer is not working on 5.0 devices, tinting through `DrawableCompat` the background seems to work on `Button` and others resources but not on `EditText`.

I discover this sentence on Android docs for `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText` afters hours struggling with this subject:

> A EditText which supports compatible features on older versions of the platform, including:
>
> > Allows dynamic tint of its background via the background tint methods in ViewCompat.

So tinting programatically method working for me on API 21, and also for the rest, would be:

```
        ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(myEditText, ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color)));
```

See reference: [AppCompatEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatEditText)